# LoDash can search dynamic object -array but it cannot do so with typed object-array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

LoDash (2.2.1) _.find() and _.where() is working with dynamic object array like

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Some name',
  event: {id: 101, text: 'Event text'}
}]
```

but not with typed object array (with 2 level deep) like

```
[new Person({
  id: 1,
  name: 'Some name',
  event: {id: 101, text: 'Event text'}
})]
// Event will be converted to Event type
```

**Please see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webadnan/13jyhvhf/2/).**

Advice?

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think this is an exact duplicate. That question is about nesting levels, this is not.

Comment: + In that question _.find was working fine with 2 level depth. But here it's creating problem. + Here the main issue is dynamic object vs typed object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **The problem**

The problem is that inside your typed array the type of `event` properties of Person objects is `Event` but as a parameter to `_.find` is `object`. Let me explain:

Lodash takes an object that you pass to `_.find` as a second parameter (let's call it target) and tries to compare properties of this object with the original one (that is passed as the 1st parameter, let's call it source). So in case of typed array:

- the source object has type `Person` (that's OK) and it has 3 properties: **id** (type int), **name** (type string) and **event** (type `Event`)
- the target object has 2 properties: **name** (type string - that's OK, as in the source object property **name** also has type string) and **event** (type object - and here's the problem!)

Take a look inside `baseIsEqual` method inside lodash: it has lots of different checks. Some of them look not pretty good but it's a victim for the performance (see more in comments started with `exit early for ...`). And inside one of these checks there's a code for getting constructors and comparing them

```
var ctorA = !support.argsObject && isArguments(a) ? Object : a.constructor,
    ctorB = !support.argsObject && isArguments(b) ? Object : b.constructor;

if (ctorA != ctorB && !(
    isFunction(ctorA) && ctorA instanceof ctorA &&
    isFunction(ctorB) && ctorB instanceof ctorB
    )) {
        return false;
}
```

And note the comment **// non `Object` object instances with different constructors are not equal**.
It that case the constructor of the source object's **event** property is the `Event` class constructor but the constructor of target object's **event** property - is `function Object() { [native code] }` as it was created as a literal objects.

## **So, how to fix it?**

Easy! You can pass to `_.find` predicate as a second parameter. So the code should be:

```
var typedResult1   = _.find(typedArray, function(p) {
    return p.name === "Adnan" && p.event && p.event.id === 101;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m16k5y41/)

Comment: The solution you have proposed is a workaround, but we can do this with native JavaScript, LoDash is not required. Anyway, I have created my own function to achieve the same :), finally thanks a lot for your time on this issue.